# C++ function template requires & for array parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

In this MCVE, the compiler complains that `processArray` can't match the parameter list (`arr`). The fix is to replace `T elements[SIZE]` with `T (&elements)[SIZE]`. Why do I need to do this, and under what circumstance? I wouldn't use `&` to pass an array into a function ordinarily. (Only reason I thought of it is that's how C++20's new version of `istream& operator>>` describes its char-array parameter.)

```
template <typename T, int SIZE>
void processArray(T elements[SIZE])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        elements[i] = 2;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[3];

    processArray(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is one of the reasons std::array exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of [array decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay).  Unless you pass an array by reference, it is going to decay into a pointer.  That means

```
void processArray(T elements[SIZE])
```

is really

```
void processArray(T* elements)
```

and there is no way to get what `SIZE` is for your template since a pointer doesn't know the size of the array it points to.

Once you make the array parameter a reference, you stop this decaying and can get the size out of the array that is passed to the function.